# Detect TCP connection/disconnection in Delphi

Tags: delphi, networking, tcp, delphi-7, indy

My application has a server form that includes a StringGrid. The server only allows 4 clients to be connected at once. It will add any tcp connections from the client-side while the list is not full.

When a new client requests a TCP connection from the server and list is full, the server should check the clients in this list to see if they are still connected. If the clients are still connected and the list is full, reject new client. If one or more clients is no longer connected, accept the new client, add it to the list and update the list.

How know clients still connect or not?

Comment: Why? Why only 4 clients? Why deny service to others? What are they supposed to do in the meantime? Why create a problem where none exists? TCP servers can cope with thousands of connections. Why four?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621273/tcpserver-client-delphi

Answer (score 6):

You should not be checking for dead clients at the time when a new client wants to connect. You should set the server's `MaxConnections` property to 4 to prevent new connections while the list is full regardless of the state of already-connected clients, and then check for dead clients periodically while they are connected using protocol-level heartbeats or tcp-level keepalives.  If a heartbeat/keepalive errors or times out, disconnect that client and remove it from the list, thus allowing a new client to connect.

Comment: clients after connect to server successfully , then disconnect from that so i cannot use MaxConnections

Comment: They disconnect after connecting but you want to leave them in your list? That does not make much sense. Please update your question to clearify your server's actual requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

- You add to the protocol the concept of 'Client Identifier'
- You decide that a 'client' is identified by its IP address (socket gives it to you).

Answer (score 1):

It will  basically depend upon your application and what makes a client unique. One way of detecting a unique client would be client IP address. If multiple clients can connect from same IP address, you need to have a unique Id per client and then while connecting to server, client needs to communicate its client id to the server which will store it and upon new connections validate it.